# Another Hash of ref functions inside Perl module

Tags: perl, methods, reference

I've got a perl object which contains a hash of hashes of coderefs (methods).

The following code **works** to call the method:

```
my $c2 = $self->{Formatter}->{"ENOTE:Final"}($self, $e);
```

It seems weird to me that I have to call it this way.  Is there another, better syntax for this?  I won't bore you with what won't work.

Thanks.

-E

Comment: Is "ENOTE:Final" a blessed reference?

Comment: No, it's just a hash key with a coderef as a value.  The quotes are there about of an abundance of caution because of the ':' character.  It may work without the quotes;  I didn't try.

Comment: Ok, so if it is a coderef. Then, the reference itself will not be passed as a first argument as it would if it was a blessed reference.  What part of the syntax is weird?

Comment: I was just wondering what the "best practice" notation might be.

Comment: I wouldn't call a chained call weird -- except for not understanding what the methods are here and why you need a chain like that.  For which reason I'd recommend to actually break it up for clarity, like in mob's answer.

Comment: It's not a chained call.  @mob's syntax is more clear as to what I was doing.  In some other post, someone suggested that the `{}->{}` notation was more clear than `{}{}`.  I see now that it is not because it looks like chained methods.  The code is just not that fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for more object-oriented syntax, there is

```
my $method = $self->{Formatter}{"ENOTE:Final"};
my $c2 = $self->$method($e);
```

Comment: Yeah, that one works, too.  I was hoping to fit it on one line, which is what led me to that weird notation above.  Your answer was what the original code looked like.

Comment: @ErikBennett The reason it looks weird is because $self is both the invocant you want to use and the structure that contains the coderef. So you need to refer to it in both those contexts.

Comment: Yes, I see that now as the source of my question.  @mob's answer illustrates that well... after taking the time to examine the role of `$self->` in each of the two lines.  Thanks, guys.